# Unable to load Firebird client library on Windows 10

Tags: delphi, dll, windows-10, firebird, client-library

Tw days ago, I installed Windows 10 build 1709 16299.192 and Embarcadero Delphi 10.2.2 Tokyo.

Since I installed them, my applications can't load the Firebird client library at runtime.

If I have an exe file compiled with older Windows and Delphi 10.2.2, it works fine, but every exe file compiled with the new Windows and Delphi are not working.

If I test a connection through `TFDConnection`, it connects successfully, but when I run the application I get this error:

> [firedac][phys][fb]-314 cannot load vendor library [c:\users\username\desktop\projectname\bin\fbclient.dll] The specified module could not be found
>   Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x86 bitness.

The path is correct, and the client library is for x86. The same application was working before installing Windows 10 build 1907 16299.192.

I tried DevArt UniDac and compiled as Win64, still have the same problem.

Reinstalling Windows and Delphi 10.2.2 (tested with 2 versions 25.0.28979.1978 and 25.0.29039.2004) still didn't help.

I think it's a permissions issue, but I don't know how to fix it.  I gave `bds.exe` all permissions over all groups, but still not working.

I have only this code on my test application

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName));
  FDPhysFBDriverLink1.VendorHome := Path;
  FDPhysFBDriverLink1.VendorLib := 'fbclient.dll';
  FDConnection1.Params.Database := Path + 'FBDV3.0.FDB';
  FDConnection1.DriverName := 'FB';
  FDConnection1.Params.UserName := 'sysdba';
  FDConnection1.Params.Password := 'masterke';
  FDConnection1.LoginPrompt := False;
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;
end;
```

Included Files and Folders in `bin` Folder:

> plugins (Folder contain engine12.dll)
>   fbclient.dll
>   ib_util.dll
>   icudt52.dll
>   icudt52l.dat
>   icuuc52.dll

Comment: Checking its not a typo but the password is "masterke" not "masterkey"?

Comment: This is not a permissions issue. The error means a required DLL could not be found. And since you are explicitly telling `TFDConnection` where `fbclient.dll` is located, most likely `fbclient.dll` itself has a dependency on another DLL that is missing on the search path. Use SysInternals Process Monitor to see what files are actually being looked for, and where they are being searched.

Comment: Do not set `VendorHome`, only `VendorLib` to the [fully qualified library file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138941/fdphysfbdriverlink-behaving-weirdly-with-vendorlib-path#comment83256089_48138941).

Comment: @Martin Password is correct Firebird password is 8 letters only so 'Y' is ignored even when you write it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau All needed files included and same application was working before updates, if it has a dependency on another DLL why FDConnection component connect successfully at design time? I will try SysInternals Process Monitor to figure out if I miss something.

Comment: @Victoria since Firebird v3 all files listed in my question are required so it's better to set 'VendorHome' and 'VendorLib', also I tried set only 'VendorLib' still get same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FDPhysFBDriverLink behaving weirdly with VendorLib Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138941): "*the driver keeps adding "\bin\" to the end of my VendorHome path*", so maybe the other DLLs are being looked for in `c:\users\username\desktop\projectname\bin\bin` instead of in `c:\users\username\desktop\projectname\bin`. That would account for the error. Process Monitor will verify/disapprove that one way or the other. Like Victoria said, just remove the `VendorHome` assignment

Comment: You write search path at design time is different, but usually when 'fbclient.dll' had a missing dependency file it create a file 'firebird.log'  and list it there but this time it didn't, I will try SysInternals Process Monitor now and back

Comment: It's not duplicate he had wrong path because he add full path at VendorLib also I checked the path in the error message and it was correct

Comment: I just ran a test project in 10.2.2 with the VendorLib pointing to the absolute location of the client dll and all worked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, I found it thru Process Monitor and it was `msvcr100.dll` copied this file to `bin` folder and it worked, I used `Firebird` for year I had never need to put this file into my app directory, it's belong to `Microsoft` and it should be found at `system32` directory, every app uses many system DLLs so should we put all that's DLLs into app directory to make sure it will work on new windows releases?

Comment: @FredS Yes it works always but this time is missing a system file `msvcr100.dll` I don't know why it works on my other pc with older windows version

Comment: Don't copy anything into system32 and don't modify security settings on program files. Stop trying crazy stuff at random that can harm your machine. Diagnose problems before trying to solve them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did try to diagnose the problem for 2 days and tried many things but I didn't think it's a missing file because it was works on other pc with older windows version and `SysErrorMessage` after `FDConnection.Connect` and `FDPhysFBDriverLink1.VendorLib := 'fbclient.dll';` retune `Access is denied`, also on windows preview 16184 and `Delphi 10.1` there was a DLL related issue fixed by change modify security settings of `bds.exe` so I gave it a try, it wasn't a crazy stuff, thank you for your helpful comment (as usual).

Comment: @Master It could be that it works on the machine with the older version of Windows because the dependency was installed by something else

Comment: @DaveNottage Yes you right, it confused me so I missed that point, thanks to everyone tried to help.

Comment: My point is that you relied I lots of guesswork to make potentially harmful changes to your machine. Instead you should have diagnosed the problem first. Guessing is never the first port of call.

Comment: Also with Firebird 3, the 'default' password for SYSDBA is actually 'masterkey' for the password, because - when using SRP authentication - it supports (very) long passwords.

Comment: Given the eventual solution, this would have been avoided if you had used the Firebird installer to install the client library.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't used to deal with this kind of problems, and with `firebird` usually it list all errors including missing DLL on `firebird.log` this time it didn't;  beside `SysErrorMessage` return `Access is denied` and old `Delphi` problems with DLL so that took me away from real reason, but now I have learned how to diagnose and solve my similar problems; sorry if I rushed to ask here before I do more diagnosing, And thank you to everyone tried to help.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 'masterke' still works with latest `Firebird` version 3.0.2, this is was just a test application so everything is default, and you right using Firebird installer is better to avoid all similar problems but I want to make sure my application work on every computer without force the user to install anything, that's why I didn't use Firebird Installers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Please answer the question, so I can accept it, thank you very much.

Comment: Masterke works if you have Legacy_Auth enabled as the authentication protocol, because then it will match the password of the 'legacy' SYSDBA user instead, which still has the old limits.

Answer (score 2):

**I just had to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=26999).**

It took me hours of trying and trying many things, I couldn't find any clue what causes it, even by debugging deep into the FD sources (Delphi 10.4.2). Too bad there is no useful error message anywhere. But then I used [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and found this dependency. Thanks to @Remy.
(Just copying msvcr100.dll didn't help in my case.)

Of course I cannot say if this would have helped here, but at least it could help many others. The symptoms were the same - it worked in the IDE (data explorer), but not in the compiled application, even though the dll was there.

By debugging I also verified that the error message asking for not only fbclient.dll, but also fbembed.dll, is not a sign of any wrong parameters: it is always looking for the second one if the first one cannot be loaded (not only if it is not found).

Comment: The required Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable depends on the Firebird version and SysInternals Process Monitor might be the better tool for tracking file access. Thanks for bringing me on the right track.